# How to turn off voiceover for Android Studio when it builds?

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio talks to me when it builds... Somehow accidentally I enabled this narrator feature, but despite my best attempts of Googling & searching for it I just cannot find the settings to turn it off. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Preferences -> Appearance Behavior -> Notifications -> scroll to Gradle Build (logging) -> Uncheck 'Read aloud'

Answer (score 0):

Try the shortcut: hold down the command key (⌘) and tap the F5 key.

If this doesn't work, follow the below steps:

1. Choose `System Preferences` from the Apple () menu.
2. Click on the `Accessibility` icon in System Preferences, then the `VoiceOver` item in the list on the left.
3. Uncheck the `Enable VoiceOver` box.

If the above both don't work, I suggest you to try this:

1. Go to `Preferences` in `Android Studio`
2. Go to `Appearance & Behaviour` --> `System Settings`
3. Under `Accessibility`, uncheck `Support screen readers` & then restart Android Studio

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that already :-/ and it only happens with Android Studio. Thanks anyways...

Comment: That didn't help either, even after the restart...really weird. But I really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I had to delete (rename to be exact) the following folder:

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.0
```

Of course, this also meant that I lost all of my IDE settings, but at least the voice over stopped.